# i Get a "Property type does not exist on type boolean" error when i try to do an inline ternary operator in vue3 typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

The error `Property type does not exist on type boolean`
shows on the show.value boolean

when I try to apply the text for the icon based on the truthiness

```
<template>

<div class="d-flex cursor-pointer justify-content-between border rounded bg-white mt-4 p-2 w-100 " @click="dropdown">
    <span>Purchase Requsition</span>
    <span class="material-icons fs-28 text-primary">
{{show.value ? 'arrow_circle_down' : 'arrow_circle_down' }}     </span>
</div>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const show = ref<boolean>(false)

function dropdown(){
   show.value = !show.value
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `show` instead of `show.value` in your template. `show.value` is only available within the `script` tag in the composition api.

```
<template>

<div class="d-flex cursor-pointer justify-content-between border rounded bg-white mt-4 p-2 w-100 " @click="dropdown">
    <span>Purchase Requsition</span>
    <span class="material-icons fs-28 text-primary">
      {{show ? 'arrow_circle_down' : 'arrow_circle_down' }}
    </span>
</div>

</template>
```